# Injected module has bad configuration

Tags: playframework, scalatest

I can't get a handle on my Play 2.6 app's test configuration. I have a spec with signature like:

```
class ChannelsComponentSpec extends PlaySpec with ServicesSpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite {

  val environment = app.environment.asJava
  val servicesModule: ServicesModule = app.injector.instanceOf[ServicesModule]
```

My test is aborted with basic substitutions missing:

```
[info]   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution: newsroom.conf @ file:/Users/ben/src/nissan-global/modules/newsroom/target/scala-2.11/classes/newsroom.conf: 466: Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${user.dir}
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigReference.resolveSubstitutions(ConfigReference.java:108)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigConcatenation.resolveSubstitutions(ConfigConcatenation.java:205)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject$ResolveModifier.modifyChildMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:379)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.modifyMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:312)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.resolveSubstitutions(SimpleConfigObject.java:398)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
```

In build.sbt my testing is configured like this:

```
fork in IntegrationTest := true
fork in Test := true

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=test.conf"
```

Any tips? I don't really understand where such specs get their configuration from.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration files within `app\conf` and `test\resources` are by default included in the classpath. If application configuration file is named `application.conf`, then nothing special needs to be done whether using Typesafe config library directly [`ConfigFactory.load()`](https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior) or Play's [configuration wrapper](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaConfig) for Typesafe config library.

We can specify an [alternative config file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#Specifying-an-alternative-configuration-file) either on the classpath or on the filesystem. Say, config file is on the classpath at `app/conf/test.conf`, then it is specified with

```
-Dconfig.resource=test.conf
```

On the other hand, if the config file is not on the application's classpath but somewhere outside in the file system, say, at `/etc/myapp/test.conf`, then it is specified with

```
-Dconfig.file=/etc/myapp/test.conf
```

In either case, we can include the default application configuration `app/conf/application.conf` within `test.conf` by having as a first line

```
include "application"
```

Now we can override particular properties from `application.conf` with corresponding test values.

Play [by default](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ConfigFile#Conventional-override-by-system-properties) runs tests in a forked JVM, so we have to use [`javaOptions`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html#Forked+JVM+options) SBT setting in order to pass system properties to the forked JVM:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=test.conf"
javaOptions in IntegrationTest += "-Dconfig.resource=integrationtest.conf"
```

To see exactly what configuration files have been loaded start SBT with

```
-Dconfig.trace=loads
```

For example, `sbt -Dconfig.trace=loads run`

Regarding your specific problem, it is quite strange that `${user.dir}` fails to substitute as [`user.dir`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) is a standard JVM system property that specifies from which directory was app launched. Is there perhaps some security policy in place restricting access to system properties?

Comment: Thanks Mario. Strangely, the ${user.dir} substitution shows up using your config.trace=loads and looks correct: ```user.dir=/home/blaha/src/myProject```

Comment: Try temporarily hardcoding value `"/home/blaha/src/myProject"` at `newsroom.conf: 466` and re-run. How far do you get?

Comment: I get a NullPointerException at what is likely the next conf substitution attempt, a `config.getString` in one of my traits. Interestingly, the null conf value is one that is set in the very same `newsroom.conf` that I hardcoded to proceed.